# Using $(PlatformTarget) for content items in csproj files

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'd like to use the selected platform target -- $(PlatformTarget) for certain content items in my .csproj file.

For example:

```
<Content Include="Plugins\$(PlatformTarget)\Plugins.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

When opening this project in VS, it seems that the platform target property is not yet resolved (the file appears to be non-existing).

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `$(Platform)`?

```
<Content Include="Plugins\$(Platform)\Plugins.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```